# Angular 5 / rxjs chain multiple HTTP calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to chain 2 http calls which I am successfully doing using a data-resolve.service to prefetch data before routing I thought I could simple reuse this logic for calling services from a component but the calls are not firing.

data-resolve.service

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  return  this.dynamicService.start()          
      .mergeMap(res => this.dynamicService.get(res))             
      .catch((error: any):any => {           
        return Observable.throw(error.error || 'Server error');
      });
}
```

Basically the same logic but called from a component:

```
this.dynamicService.genericSave(httpMethod, appDetails)      
  .mergeMap(res => {return this.dynamicService.get(res)})
  .catch((error: any):any => {
    console.log(error);
  })     
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

dynamic service:

```
get(res){
  const submitEndpoint = res.submitStepLink;
  const method = res.method;
  const req = new HttpRequest(method, submitEndpoint, '', {

  });
  return this.http.request(req)
    .retry(3);
 }
```

Is the 2nd call still cold?

Comment: Where do you call `.subscribe`?

Comment: I don't have a subscribe in the 2nd code block. Does the angular route resolver basically do the subscribe automagically? Which would be why i'm missing it.

Comment: It might. I'm not familiar with angular router. If you're calling `dataResolveService.resolve()` you will have to subscribe at some point

Comment: By the way you can probably make this a lot simpler: `this.dynamicService.start().mergeMap(res => this.dynamicService.get(res)).catch(...)` should be all you need.

Comment: @ExplosionPills For some reason only the options call for genericSave is going out but not the actual POST. Any Ideas?

Comment: The OPTIONS call is failing?

Comment: why are you throwing another error inside the catch?

Comment: @Ricardo That was a mistake.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Correct. Not sure why.